# Angular webpack.config- Icon's not loading

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I have been trying to load icons in micro UI, imported library for icons is not loading. I have updated the webpack.config with loaders

```
module.exports = (config, options) => {
  config.output = {
    ...config.output,
    uniqueName: "claimApp",
    publicPath: "http://localhost:7001/",
  } 

  config.module ={ 
    rules:[{ test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg|)$/, use:"url-loader" } ]}
```

However this raises other issues for other other file types

```
./src/app/app.module.ts:21:63 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (21:63)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
```

I tried to install ts-loader, it said it was installed but never appeared in node_modules or package.json.

Is there a way to use url-loader for only font types ? the other file type issues only appeared when this specific loader was added. I tried the less-loader for .less files and received the the error that no string was returned.

````
./src/styles.less:2:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| /* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
> @import "../node_modules/```
````